# Program for a quiz competition

Tags: java, sql, swing

I am writing a program for a quiz competition in my college similar to "Who wants to be a Millionaire" or "Kaun Banega Crorepati".
I am retrieving questions from a database having 6 columns in all; 1 for question, 4 for options and 1 for correct answer. The question is in the form of a JLabel and the options in the form of JButtons. In addition, I have Check and Next JButtons.
However when I try to retrieve data from the database, I get a NullPointerException. I have posted the code here.

I hope you guys can help me fix the program so that I can run the quiz competition in my college successfully for students.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class KBP{
    public static void main(String[] argv){
        JFrame jf = new Frames();
        jf.pack();
        jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        jf.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Frames extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("logo.jpg");

    JLabel questions;
    JButton option1;
    JButton option2;
    JButton option3;
    JButton option4;
    JButton check = new JButton("Check");
    JButton next = new JButton("Next");

    Statement st = null;
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public Frames(){
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);
//      System.out.println("                   "+number());


        setSize(((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth()),((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight()));
        System.out.println("width is             "+getWidth());
        System.out.println("height is            "+getHeight());

        setIconImage(logo.getImage());
        setTitle("Kaun Banega PhysicsPati");

        getContentPane().add(questions);
        questions = new JLabel("Question "+number()+":    "+question(), SwingConstants.CENTER);
        questions.setBounds(0,(int)(getHeight()/5), getWidth(),60);
        System.out.println("bounds of question is            "+questions.getBounds().toString());
        questions.setFont(new Font("ARIAL",1,20));
        questions.setForeground(Color.RED);

        getContentPane().add(option1);
        option1 = new JButton(first());
        option1.setBounds(100,(int)(2*getHeight()/5),500,40);
        System.out.println("bounds of option 1 is            "+option1.getBounds().toString());
//      option1.setBounds((int)(getWidth()/100),(int)(2*getHeight()/5),(int)(2*getWidth()/5)-(int)(getWidth()/100),40);
        option1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        option1.addActionListener(this);

        getContentPane().add(option2);
        option2 = new JButton(second());
        option2.setBounds(750,(int)(2*getHeight()/5),500,40);
        System.out.println("bounds of option 2 is            "+option2.getBounds().toString());
//      option2.setBounds((int)(getWidth()/100)+(int)(getWidth()/2),(int)(2*getHeight()/5),(int)(2*getWidth()/5)-(int)(getWidth()/100),40);
        option2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        option2.addActionListener(this);

        getContentPane().add(option3);
        option3 = new JButton(third());
        option3.setBounds(100,(int)(3*getHeight()/5),500,40);
        System.out.println("bounds of option 3 is            "+option3.getBounds().toString());
//      option3.setBounds((int)(getWidth()/100),(int)(3*getHeight()/5),(int)(2*getWidth()/2)-(int)(getWidth()/100),40);
        option3.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        option3.addActionListener(this);

        getContentPane().add(option4);
        option4 = new JButton(fourth());
        option4.setBounds(750,(int)(3*getHeight()/5),500,40);
        System.out.println("bounds of option 4 is            "+option4.getBounds().toString());
//      option4.setBounds((int)(getWidth()/100)+(int)(getWidth()/2),(int)(3*getHeight()/5),(int)(getWidth()/2)-(int)(getWidth()/100),40);
        option4.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        option4.addActionListener(this);

        getContentPane().add(check);
        check.setBounds((int)(getWidth()/2),(int)(4*getHeight()/5),100,40);
        System.out.println("bounds of check is            "+check.getBounds().toString());
//      check.setSize(100,40);
        check.addActionListener(this);
        check.setVisible(false);


        getContentPane().add(next);
        next.setBounds((int)(getWidth()/2),(int)(4*getHeight()/5),100,40);
        System.out.println("bounds of next is            "+next.getBounds().toString());
//      next.setBounds(683,614,100,40);
        next.addActionListener(this);
//      next.addActionListener(this);
        next.setVisible(false);
        next.setBackground(Color.PINK);

    }

    public void connect(){
        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
            System.out.println("after classforname");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:quiz","","");
            System.out.println("after drivermanager");
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Questions");
        }catch(Exception e){
//          System.out.println("Exception caught : " + e.toString());
        }finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e3){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
        }
    }

    public int number(){
        int n =0;
        connect();
        try{
            if (rs.next()){
                n = rs.getInt(1)-1;
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
//          System.out.println("Exception caught : " + e.toString());
        }finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e3){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
        }
        return n;
    }

    public String question(){
        String q = "";
        connect();
        try{
            if (rs.next()){
                q = rs.getString(2);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
//          System.out.println("Exception caught : " + e.toString());
        }finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e3){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
        }
        return q;
    }

    public String first(){
        String f = "";
        connect();
        try{
            if (rs.next()){
                f = "A                      "+rs.getString(3);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
//          System.out.println("Exception caught : " + e.toString());
        }finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e3){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e4){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e4.toString());
            }
        }
        return f;
    }

    public String second(){
        String s = "";
        connect();
        try{
            if (rs.next()){
                s = "B                      "+rs.getString(4);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
//          System.out.println("Exception caught : " + e.toString());
        }finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e3){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e4){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e4.toString());
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    public String third(){
        String t = "";
        connect();
        try{
            if (rs.next()){
                t = "C                      "+rs.getString(5);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
//          System.out.println("Exception caught : " + e.toString());
        }finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e3){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e4){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e4.toString());
            }
        }
        return t;
    }

    public String fourth(){
        String f = "";
        connect();
        try{
            if (rs.next()){
                f = "D                      "+rs.getString(6);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
//          System.out.println("Exception caught : " + e.toString());
        }finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e3){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e4){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e4.toString());
            }
        }
        return f;
    }

    public String correct(){
        String c = "";
        connect();
        try{
            if (rs.next()){
                c = rs.getString(7);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
//          System.out.println("Exception caught : " + e.toString());
        }finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e3){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e4){
//              System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e4.toString());
            }
        }
        return c;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if (ae.getSource()==option1){
            option1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            option1.removeActionListener(this);
            option2.removeActionListener(this);
            option3.removeActionListener(this);
            option4.removeActionListener(this);
            check.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("bound of check is            "+check.getBounds().toString());
            System.out.println(option1.getText());
        }else if (ae.getSource()==option2){
            option2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            option1.removeActionListener(this);
            option2.removeActionListener(this);
            option3.removeActionListener(this);
            option4.removeActionListener(this);
            check.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("bound of check is            "+check.getBounds().toString());
        }else if (ae.getSource()==option3){
            option3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            option1.removeActionListener(this);
            option2.removeActionListener(this);
            option3.removeActionListener(this);
            option4.removeActionListener(this);
            check.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("bound of check is            "+check.getBounds().toString());
        }else if (ae.getSource()==option4){
            option4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            option1.removeActionListener(this);
            option2.removeActionListener(this);
            option3.removeActionListener(this);
            option4.removeActionListener(this);
            check.setVisible(true);
            System.out.println("bound of check is            "+check.getBounds().toString());
        }else if (ae.getSource()==check){
            option1.removeActionListener(this);
            option2.removeActionListener(this);
            option3.removeActionListener(this);
            option4.removeActionListener(this);
            check.setVisible(false);
            System.out.println("bounds of check is            "+check.getBounds().toString());
            System.out.println("Checked");
            System.out.println("bound of next is            "+next.getBounds().toString());         
            next.setVisible(true);

            connect();

            if (option1.getText().contains(correct())){
                option1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }else if (option2.getText().contains(correct())){
                option2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }else if (option3.getText().contains(correct())){
                option3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }else if (option4.getText().contains(correct())){
                option4.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }

        }else if (ae.getSource()==next){
            System.out.println("Next");
            System.out.println("bounds of next is            "+next.getBounds().toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `I have posted the code here` - did you?

Comment: If you've done even a little searching on solving a NullPointerException (NPE), you'll know that the most important bit of information that we need is the exception's associated stacktrace and some identification of the line that causes it, something that the stacktrace will tell you, and unfortunately neither of which you've posted here with your question. Please fix this so that we can help you.

Comment: Most importantly, you need to learn the general concepts of how to debug a NPE (NullPointerException). You should critically read your exception's stacktrace to find the line of code at fault, the line that throws the exception, and then inspect that line carefully, find out which variable is null, and then trace back into your code to see why. You will run into these again and again, trust me.

Comment: Thanks. I slowly learnt to debug. :)

Comment: Another issue now is in spite of using setBound() for JButton, it fills the entire frame. No exceptions or errors are shown.  Another JButton with the same code except name changed works properly.

Answer (score 0):

I am pasting the new code. Everything works fine except for the JButton "Next". Even if I comment all the lines except for this JButton.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.filechooser.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class KBP{
    public static void main(String[] argv){
        JFrame jf = new Frames();
        jf.pack();
        jf.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH); 
        jf.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        jf.setVisible(true);
    }
}

class Frames extends JFrame implements ActionListener{
    Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
    ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("logo.jpg");

    JLabel questions = new JLabel();
    JButton option1 = new JButton();
    JButton option2 = new JButton();
    JButton option3 = new JButton();
    JButton option4 = new JButton();
    JButton check = new JButton("Check");
    JButton next = new JButton("");

    Statement st = null;
    Connection con = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    public Frames(){
        super();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(3);


        setSize(((int) tk.getScreenSize().getWidth()),((int) tk.getScreenSize().getHeight()));
        System.out.println("width is             "+getWidth());
        System.out.println("height is            "+getHeight());

        setIconImage(logo.getImage());
        setTitle("Kaun Banega PhysicsPati");

        getContentPane().add(questions);
        questions.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        questions.setText("Question "+number()+":    "+question());
        questions.setBounds(0,(int)(getHeight()/5), getWidth(),60);
//      System.out.println("bounds of questions is            "+questions.getBounds().toString());
        questions.setFont(new Font("ARIAL",1,20));
        questions.setForeground(Color.RED);

        getContentPane().add(option1);
        option1.setText(first());
        option1.setBounds(100,(int)(2*getHeight()/5),500,40);
//      System.out.println("bounds of option 1 is            "+option1.getBounds().toString());
//      option1.setBounds((int)(getWidth()/100),(int)(2*getHeight()/5),(int)(2*getWidth()/5)-(int)(getWidth()/100),40);
        option1.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        option1.addActionListener(this);

        getContentPane().add(option2);
        option2.setText(second());
        option2.setBounds(750,(int)(2*getHeight()/5),500,40);
//      System.out.println("bounds of option 2 is            "+option2.getBounds().toString());
//      option2.setBounds((int)(getWidth()/100)+(int)(getWidth()/2),(int)(2*getHeight()/5),(int)(2*getWidth()/5)-(int)(getWidth()/100),40);
        option2.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        option2.addActionListener(this);

        getContentPane().add(option3);
        option3.setText(third());
        option3.setBounds(100,(int)(3*getHeight()/5),500,40);
//      System.out.println("bounds of option 3 is            "+option3.getBounds().toString());
//      option3.setBounds((int)(getWidth()/100),(int)(3*getHeight()/5),(int)(2*getWidth()/2)-(int)(getWidth()/100),40);
        option3.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        option3.addActionListener(this);

        getContentPane().add(option4);
        option4.setText(fourth());
        option4.setBounds(750,(int)(3*getHeight()/5),500,40);
//      System.out.println("bounds of option 4 is            "+option4.getBounds().toString());
//      option4.setBounds((int)(getWidth()/100)+(int)(getWidth()/2),(int)(3*getHeight()/5),(int)(getWidth()/2)-(int)(getWidth()/100),40);
        option4.setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        option4.addActionListener(this);

        getContentPane().add(check);
        check.setBounds((int)(getWidth()/2),(int)(4*getHeight()/5),100,40);
//      check.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        System.out.println("bounds of check is            "+check.getBounds().toString());
//      check.setSize(100,40);
        check.addActionListener(this);
        check.setVisible(false);


        getContentPane().add(next);
        next.setBounds(0,0,100,40);
        next.setText("Next");
//      next.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        System.out.println("bounds of next is            "+next.getBounds().toString());
//      next.setSize(100,40);
        next.addActionListener(this);
        next.setVisible(false);
        next.setBackground(Color.PINK);

    }

    public void connect(){
        try{
            Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
//          System.out.println("after classforname");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:quiz","","");
//          System.out.println("after drivermanager");
            st = con.createStatement();
            rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Questions");
            if (rs.next()){

//              System.out.println("   "+rs.getString(2));
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught in connect : " + e.toString());
        }/*finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e2.toString());
            }
        }*/
    }

    public int number(){
        int n =0;
        connect();
        try{
//          if (rs.next()){
                n = rs.getInt(1)-1;
//          }

        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught in n : " + e.toString());
        }/*finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in n : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs==null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in n : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in n : " + e2.toString());
            }
        }*/
//      System.out.println("   "+n);
        return n;
    }

    public String question(){
        String q = "";
        connect();
        try{
//          if (rs.next()){
                q = rs.getString(2);
//          }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught in q : " + e.toString());
        }/*finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caughtt in q : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs==null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caughtt in q : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caughtt in q : " + e2.toString());
            }
        }*/
//      System.out.println("           "+q);
        return q;
    }

    public String first(){
        String f = "";
        connect();
        try{
//          if (rs.next()){
                f = "A                      "+rs.getString(3);
//          }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caughtt in f : " + e.toString());
        }/*finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in f : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in f : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e4){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in f : " + e4.toString());
            }
        }*/
        return f;
    }

    public String second(){
        String s = "";
        connect();
        try{
//          if (rs.next()){
                s = "B                      "+rs.getString(4);
//          }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught in s : " + e.toString());
        }/*finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in s : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in s : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e4){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in s : " + e4.toString());
            }
        }*/
        return s;
    }

    public String third(){
        String t = "";
        connect();
        try{
//          if (rs.next()){
                t = "C                      "+rs.getString(5);
//          }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught in t : " + e.toString());
        }/*finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in t : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in t : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e4){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught : " + e4.toString());
            }
        }*/
        return t;
    }

    public String fourth(){
        String f = "";
        connect();
        try{
//          if (rs.next()){
                f = "D                      "+rs.getString(6);
//          }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught in fo : " + e.toString());
        }/*finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in fo : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in fo : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e4){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in fo : " + e4.toString());
            }
        }*/
        return f;
    }

    public String correct(){
        String c = "";
        connect();
        try{
//          if (rs.next()){
                c = rs.getString(7);
//          }
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("Exception caught in c : " + e.toString());
        }/*finally{
            try{
                if(con!=null){
                    con.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in c : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(rs!=null){
                    rs.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e2){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in c : " + e2.toString());
            }
            try{
                if(st!=null){
                    st.close();
                } 
            }catch (Exception e4){
                System.out.println("Exceptions caught in c : " + e4.toString());
            }
        }*/
        return c;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
        if (ae.getSource()==option1){
            option1.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            option1.removeActionListener(this);
            option2.removeActionListener(this);
            option3.removeActionListener(this);
            option4.removeActionListener(this);
            check.setVisible(true); //check.setVisible(true);
//          System.out.println("bound of check is            "+check.getBounds().toString());
            System.out.println(option1.getText());
        }else if (ae.getSource()==option2){
            option2.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            option1.removeActionListener(this);
            option2.removeActionListener(this);
            option3.removeActionListener(this);
            option4.removeActionListener(this);
            check.setVisible(true);
//          System.out.println("bound of check is            "+check.getBounds().toString());
        }else if (ae.getSource()==option3){
            option3.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            option1.removeActionListener(this);
            option2.removeActionListener(this);
            option3.removeActionListener(this);
            option4.removeActionListener(this);
            check.setVisible(true);
//          System.out.println("bound of check is            "+check.getBounds().toString());
        }else if (ae.getSource()==option4){
            option4.setBackground(Color.YELLOW);
            option1.removeActionListener(this);
            option2.removeActionListener(this);
            option3.removeActionListener(this);
            option4.removeActionListener(this);
            check.setVisible(true);
//          System.out.println("bound of check is            "+check.getBounds().toString());
        }else if (ae.getSource()==check){
            option1.removeActionListener(this);
            option2.removeActionListener(this);
            option3.removeActionListener(this);
            option4.removeActionListener(this);
            check.setVisible(false);
//          System.out.println("bounds of check is            "+check.getBounds().toString());
            System.out.println("Checked");
            System.out.println("bound of next is            "+next.getBounds().toString());         
//          next.setVisible(true);

            connect();

            if (option1.getText().contains(correct())){
                option1.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }else if (option2.getText().contains(correct())){
                option2.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }else if (option3.getText().contains(correct())){
                option3.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }else if (option4.getText().contains(correct())){
                option4.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
            }

        }else if (ae.getSource()==next){
            System.out.println("Next");
            System.out.println("bounds of next is            "+next.getBounds().toString());
        }
    }
}
```